# JS setCustomValidity not work at first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a custom validity message to my form, and there are some problem.

The validity message will show after click two times.
and if I don't input correct word "text" first time, then it will not submit anymore.
what's the problem in my code.

JS:

```js
function a(){
 jQuery("#text")[0].setCustomValidity("");
  if (jQuery("#text").val() == "text"){
        return confirm('sure?');
        }
  jQuery("#text")[0].setCustomValidity("Incorrect");
         return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return a();">
     <input type='text' id="text"/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: you are returning `confirm`

Comment: yeah, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to check below solution:

```js
$(document).on('click',"#submit_btn", function()
{
     if($("#text").val() === "text")
        return confirm('sure?');
     else
       $("#text")[0].setCustomValidity("Incorrect");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="/" method="post">
     <input type='text' id="text"/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit_btn"/>
  </form>
```